# Displaying XML from a database

Tags: javascript

I would like to display an XML document in the browser.  I would like to have the XML displayed in collapsed form with the ability to expand it - like you can when you view an XML document directly with a browser.  Is this possible?
I can now display the XML as text with this script:

```
// Handle_OnRowSelectSETIData
function Handle_OnRowSelectSETIData(sender, args)// When the user selects a SETIData do this script
{
    var _SETIDataRow = args["Row"];
    SETIData_ID = _SETIDataRow.getDataItem()["SETIData_ID"];// Picks up the ID of the data
    _HitSML = document.getElementById("HitSML");// Pick up the place where it will be displayed
    _HitSML.innerText = _SETIDataRow.getDataItem()["SML"];// Get the XML itself and send it to the browser
}
```

You can see a sample here:[Current Example](http://www.seti.net/archive/ra-00/andromeda/adhil/target.php)
(Select the "620" in the bottom grid render...)
[Example Link](http://www.seti.net/archive/ra-00/andromeda/adhil/target.php)

Comment: You have a couple global variables, is it intentional? (Namely, `SETIData_ID` and `_HitSML`)

Comment: Yes they are.  You can see the results of this code at:http://www.seti.net/archive/ra-00/andromeda/adhil/target.php
(select the '620' at the bottom grid rendering)

Comment: Well, you could simply put a iframe with the src pointing to your XML, or you might be interested in things such as http://xmlgrid.net/.

Comment: Why don't you use JSON Editor online? You can include the project in your project =) https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/

Comment: What I am looking for is something like this:   [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml)